# Spark structured streaming avoid delay and checkpointing: startingOffsets latest does not work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

i am developing a **spark structured streaming** process for a real time application

I need to read current kafka messages without any delay.

Messages older than 30 seconds are not relevant in this project.

I am reading old messages with a big delay from current timestamp ...(minutes) .. it seems that spark structured streaming does not use well startingOffsets property to latest.

I guess that the problem is the HDFS checkpoint location of topic where i write ...

**I do not want to read old messages**, only are important **current ones**!!

I have test many different configurations, kafka properties, etc .. but did not work ..

Here is  my code and **relevant config** (kafka.bootstrap.servers and kafka.ssl.* properties are not include here but exists)

- Spark version: **2.4.0-cdh6.3.3**

> Consumer properties used at readStream

```
offsets.retention.minutes -> 1,
groupIdPrefix -> 710b6fb4-4454-4a52-819e-f565e047ecb7, 
subscribe -> topic_x, 
consumer.override.auto.offset.reset -> latest, 
failOnDataLoss -> false, 
startingOffset -> latest, 
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms -> 1000
```

> Reader Kafka topic readerB

```
      val readerB = spark
        .readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .options(consumerProperties)
        .load()
```

> Producer properties used at writeStream

```
topic -> topic_destination,
checkpointLocation -> checkPointLocation
```

> Write stream block

```
val sendToKafka = dtXXXKafka
        .select(to_sr(struct($"*"), xxx_out_topic, xxx_out_topic, schemaRegistryNamespace).alias("value"))
        .writeStream
        .format("kafka")
        .options(producerProperties(properties, xxx_agg_out_topic, xxx_agg_out_localcheckpoint_hdfs))
        .outputMode("append")
        .start()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `startingOffset` property is applied **only when a query is started**, meaning, for the first batch of your streaming query only. Afterwards, this property is ignored and the batches are defined according to the checkpoint data.

In your case, the streaming query starts by reading only the freshest data from your kafka topic (thanks to the `startingOffset -> latest` setting). BUT, The second batch (and all the next batches) will be defined according to the checkpoint, or in other words, they will start exactly from where the previous batch ended - the `offsets` folder in the checkpoint contains the ending offsets (exclusive) for each batch so batch X starts from the offsets saved for the batch X-1. **This is how the exactly once delivery semantics is achieved in spark structured streaming**.

docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

If you want to process only the data from the last 30 seconds, I would suggest you to filter the Dataframe by the `timestamp` field to include only the data from the desired time frame.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Gabip. I am trying to filter by **current_timestamp** but the data is **delayed** too `val readerS2000b = spark
        .readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .options(mpKafkaPropertiesRAW)
        .load()
        .withColumn("current_batch_timestamp", current_timestamp)
        .filter($"current_batch_timestamp" > current_timestamp - expr("INTERVAL 30 seconds"))` .... current_batch_timestamp is delayed in minutes ...... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set properly the `trigger interval`? it should be set to 30 seconds in your case.

Comment: Yes, i have trigger property set to 30 seconds at writestream and each batch run properly, but the messages are still delayed several minutes ... I am really surprise that spark does not have some configuration to ignore poder messages and avoid this situation

Comment: This is not a bug, this is a feature :) Spark structured streaming guarantees exactly once delivery semantics and the behaviour you suggest violates it. How long does it take to finish a batch for your streamer? does it finish in less than 30 seconds?